# How to stop speech recognition on textarea?

Tags: jquery, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a `<textarea>` and i don't want to allow to my users to use speech recognition on any device.

I tried this JQuery method but I can not block speech recognition on my IPhone or Chrome Desktop.

```
$('#answerText').bind('webkitspeechchange',function(e) {
    console.log("Speech recognition is not allowed");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What about those who use speech recognition for accessibility? This is a very odd requirement.

Comment: You are right but my answer / question site based on the keyboard write speed challenges

Answer (score 0):

You can try emptying the `<textarea>` element, and display a message in the text are to not to use speech recognition.

```
$('#answerText').bind('webkitspeechchange',function(e) {
$('#answerText').text("Speech recognition is not allowed. Please use the keyboard");
e.preventDefault();
});
```

This way, the user can use the speech recognition, but the result will not display in the text area. Instead, they will get the message and know that you want them to use the keyboard.

But like  Rory McCrossan said, I am not sure if you want to implement this especially where users with special needs are expected.